# Compute equidistant GPS point around a center

Tags: ruby, gps, rubygems, geometry, coordinates

I have a question about some GPS calculations.
My problem is as follow :

I have a specific point P, and I want to compute N points around P.

Here is the algorithm :

```
P = (x, y) // latitude, longitude
N = 8
angle_size = 360/N

points = []

for i in 1..N
    points.push compute_100meter(P, angle_size*i)
end
```

In this example, I'm trying to compute 8 equidistant point within 100 meter from P.

Is anyone know a *ruby gem* allowing me to do so ?
My problem is to write the content of `compute_100meter`

**EDIT:**

I have to take into account the earth curvature and get the point coordinates in degree (latitude, longitude).

Comment: You don't need a gem, this is a simple geometry problem. 100m is your radius. Simply lookup the equation to calculate a point 100m from the circle's center point, given the angle.

Comment: I have to take into account the earth curvature, I edited my question.

Comment: You're right, I apologize. I see why you want a code library now, because you won't always be doing calculations near the equator where 100m is approximately like the geometry question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the radius is small enough (and 100 meters should be, unless you're right next to the north or south pole), a simple linear approximation should do well enough:

```ruby
def perimeter_point(lat, lon, angle, radius)
    # convert angle from degrees to radians
    angle *= Math::PI / 180
    # convert meters to degrees approximately, assuming spherical Earth
    radius /= 6371000 * Math::PI / 180
    # calculate relative length of the circle of longitude compared to equator
    scale = Math.cos( lat * Math::PI / 180 );
    # add offsets to longitude and latitude and return them
    # (I'm assuming that angle = 0 means due east)
    lat += radius * Math.sin(angle)
    lon += radius * Math.cos(angle) / scale
    return lat, lon
end
```

Note that, if your center point is near the 180th meridian, this could return longitudes below -180 or above +180.  If that's a problem, check for it and normalize as needed.  (Output latitudes outside the ±90 range are also technically possible, if the center point is near the north or south pole, but the approximation I used breaks down close to the poles anyway.)